# Keyboard inactive after bootx64 for MinnowBoard

Tags: keyboard, intel, yocto, uefi

I am working first time with a minnowboard hardware from Intel and have create a core-image-minimal using Yocto project. When I power on the Minnowboard, I enter the UEFI shell where I execute following commands:

> 1. `connect -r`
> 2. `map -r`
> 3. `fs0:`
> 4. `bootx64`

The keyboard works fine for all this process. Then I enter the GRUB menu and select "BOOT".

When the core-image-minimal boots, I am asked to login.

At this point, the keyboard doesn't work. I inspected the boot command and it goes something like this:

> 

1. `setparams 'boot'`
2. `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootwait quiet console=ttys0,115200 console=tty0`

I am not sure why keyboard works in the UEFI shell but not when the linux image is booted. Do I need to add some option like `-usb` or `-usbdevice` to this boot commands for it to detect keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds horrible but apparently the issue was with my keyboard which is a make from "Cherry". When I plugged in a Dell keyboard, it works seamlessly. Duh!